# How to get a list of installed applications without booting into Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, migration

I have a laptop whose HDD is dying and has become read only. I can't boot the system into Ubuntu but I can read the Ubuntu partition using a live disk. Is there any way that I can get a list of installed applications (on the Ubuntu partition) so that I can easily install them on a new hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to tell `dpkg` to search the database on the inactive filesystem. For example if you have mounted the failing disk's root filesystem at `/mnt/old` then you can try

```
dpkg --admindir=/mnt/old/var/lib/dpkg --get-selections
```

or

```
dpkg-query -l --admindir=/mnt/old/var/lib/dpkg
```

The `dpkg --get-selections` command would be preferable (if it works) since you can import its output directly via `dpkg --set-selections` on the new system.

Comment: Didn't realize you could specify the database directly. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of different things, just from looking at the HDD:

1. Look at `/opt` for those random packages that get installed there
2. Look at `/usr/share/applications` to get a listing of all the applications that have a shortcut that shows up when you search Unity.
3. Look at `/etc/` to see if you've missed anything that's just a CLI tool.

If you ever get it to start up, you could type:

`sudo dpkg --get-selections`

That will give you the most comprehensive list.